# Checking if argv[i] exists C++

Tags: c++, input, program-entry-point

If I ran a C++ program

```
./program arg1
```

argv[1] exists, however is there a way to check if argv[2] exists?

Comment: What about checking `argc`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, look at the value of `argc`:

```
if (argc > 2) {
  ... use argv[2] ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, `argv[i]` ends with `NULL`. `argc` is `number of arguments` passed to main function. Get an idea from following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i=0;
    while(argv[i]!=NULL){
        printf("\n %s is argv %d ",argv[i],i);
            i++;
    }
        
    printf("\n");
}
```

execute:

```
desktop:~$ gcc main.c  -o main 
desktop:~$ ./main grijesh thisiscrazy4
```

here:

```
./main is argv 0 
grijesh is argv 1
thisiscrazy4 is argv 2
```

hHere argv was - `"./main", "grijesh"," thisiscrazy4", NULL` and `argc` = `3`.

`argv[0]` is the executable name (path of execution) that can be used to pint with error statements.
`argv` is called the argument vector and `argc` is called the argument-counter. you can use another variable name also.

Read about [full syntax of main() function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) that also includes environment variables.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

[Learn HEAR](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Environment-variables.html)

Comment: In this example `argc == 3` actually – path of execution is also considered as an argument.

Comment: `ADDED MORE INFORMATION ABOUT MAIN SYNTAX`

Comment: @Hugo No , `x = argv[i] != NULL`  returns `0` or `1` depending on value of `argv[i]` where `x = argv[i]` results a pointer. Yes, because every non-zero is equivalent to True in C so `if (argv[i] != NULL)`  can be written as `if (argv[i])`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of `main` says it all:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

The first parameter here, `argc` carries the value of `Number_Of_Arguments(argv[])_Present`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the other way around. Test the count of `argc`, there by you can know the presence of `argv[n]`.